How to get elements to be Reactive in this particular case (Vue3, Pinia)?
Hi everyone and first of all thanks anyone who will try to help.
I have this code here which is used for the menu in the vue (it is vue component):
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed, ref, onMounted, watch, onBeforeUnmount } from "vue";
import { useRoute, useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { logoDark, logoLight, logoSm } from "@/assets/images/utils";
import { getMenuItems } from "@/app/layout/utils";
import SubMenu from "@/app/layout/menu/SubMenu.vue";
import { useLayoutStore } from "@/store/layout";
import { LucideNetwork } from "lucide-vue-next";
import { LAYOUTS, SIDEBAR_SIZE } from "@/app/const";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { MenuItemType, SubMenuType } from "@/app/layout/types";
import { useAppStore } from '@/store/index';

const layoutStore = computed(() => useLayoutStore());
const layoutType = computed(() => layoutStore.value.layoutType);
const isHorizontal = computed(() => layoutType.value === LAYOUTS.HORIZONTAL);

const route = useRoute();
const router = useRouter();
const path = computed(() => route.path);

const LanguageStore = useAppStore();
const t = computed(() => LanguageStore.translations);

// Define menuItems as a ref and update it whenever the language changes
const menuItems = ref<MenuItemType[]>([]);
menuItems.value = getMenuItems(t);

const sideBarComponent = computed(() => {
  const sideBarSize = layoutStore.value.sideBarSize;

  if (sideBarSize === SIDEBAR_SIZE.SMALL) {
    return "div";
  } else {
    return "simplebar";
  }
});
const onLogoClick = () => {
  router.push("/");
};
const mappedData: any = menuItems.value.map((item) => {
  if (item.subMenu) {
    const nestedSubMenu = item.subMenu.map((subMenu: SubMenuType) => {
      if (subMenu.subMenu) {
        return {
          ...subMenu,
          isActive: false,
          id: uuidv4()
        };
      }
      return {
        ...subMenu
      };
    });

    return {
      ...item,
      subMenu: nestedSubMenu,
      isActive: false,
      id: uuidv4()
    };
  }
  return {
    ...item,
    id: uuidv4()
  };
});

const clientWidth = ref(document.documentElement.clientWidth);

const menuItemData = ref<MenuItemType[]>(mappedData);

const onWindowResize = () => {
  clientWidth.value = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  if (isHorizontal.value) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setupHorizontalMenu();
    }, 300);
  } else {
    menuItemData.value = mappedData;
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);

  if (isHorizontal.value) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setupHorizontalMenu();
    }, 300);
  }
  document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", (event: any) => {
    isSubMenu(event.target);
  });
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", (event: any) => {
    isSubMenu(event.target);
  });
  window.removeEventListener("resize", setupHorizontalMenu);
  window.removeEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
});

const isSubMenu = (element: HTMLElement | null): boolean => {
  if (!element) {
    hideActivation();
    return false;
  }
  return (
    element.classList.contains("submenu-dropdown") ||
    element.classList.contains("app-menu") ||
    isSubMenu(element.parentElement)
  );
};

watch(layoutType, (newVal: string) => {
  if (newVal === LAYOUTS.HORIZONTAL) {
    setupHorizontalMenu();
  } else {
    menuItemData.value = mappedData;
  }
});

const setupHorizontalMenu = () => {
  if (clientWidth.value >= 768) {
    window.addEventListener("resize", setupHorizontalMenu);

    let isMoreMenu = false;
    const navData = mappedData.filter(
      (menuItem: MenuItemType) => !menuItem.isHeader
    );
    const horizontalMenuEle = document.querySelector(".app-menu");
    const navbarNav = document.querySelector(".navbar-header");
    if (navbarNav) {
      const fullMenuWidth = navbarNav.clientWidth - 100 || 0;

      let totalItemsWidth = 0;
      let visibleItems: MenuItemType[] = [];
      let hiddenItems: MenuItemType[] = []; // Add type annotation here

      for (let i = 0; i < navData.length; i++) {
        const element: HTMLElement = horizontalMenuEle?.querySelector(
          "#navbar-nav"
        )?.children[i] as HTMLElement;
        const itemWidth = element?.offsetWidth || 0;
        totalItemsWidth += itemWidth;

        if (totalItemsWidth + 250 <= fullMenuWidth) {
          visibleItems.push(navData[i]);
        } else {
          hiddenItems.push(navData[i]);
        }
      }

      const moreMenuItem = {
        title: "more",
        icon: LucideNetwork,
        isActive: false,
        subMenu: hiddenItems,
        id: uuidv4(),
        stateVariables: isMoreMenu,
        click: (e: any) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          isMoreMenu = !isMoreMenu;
        }
      };

      let updatedMenuItems: any = [...visibleItems];
      if (hiddenItems.length) {
        updatedMenuItems.push(moreMenuItem);
      }

      menuItemData.value = updatedMenuItems;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      handleDropdownMenu();
    }, 500);
  } else {
    menuItemData.value = mappedData;
  }
};



const toggleActivation = (menuItemId: string) => {
  let hasSubMenu = false; // Flag to track if the element has submenu items

  menuItemData.value = menuItemData.value.map((item: MenuItemType) => {
    if (item.id === menuItemId) {
      return {
        ...item,
        isActive: !item.isActive
      };
    } else if (item.subMenu) {
      const nestedSubmenu = getActivations(menuItemId, item);
      const firstLevelMenu = {
        ...item,
        isActive: nestedSubmenu.some(
          (subMenu: SubMenuType) => subMenu.isActive
        ),
        subMenu: nestedSubmenu
      };

      // Update flag if submenu exists
      if (!hasSubMenu && nestedSubmenu.length > 0) {
        hasSubMenu = true;
      }

      return firstLevelMenu;
    }
    return { ...item, isActive: false };
  });

  // Call closeSidebar() only if the element doesn't have submenu items
  if (!hasSubMenu) {
    closeSidebar();
  }
};



const closeSidebar = () => {
  const backdropOverlay = document.querySelector(".backdrop-overlay");
  if (backdropOverlay instanceof HTMLElement) {
    backdropOverlay.click();
  }
};

const getActivations: any = (menuItemId: string, menuItem: MenuItemType) => {
  const preparedData = menuItem.subMenu?.map((subMenu: SubMenuType) => {
    if (menuItemId && subMenu.id === menuItemId) {
      return {
        ...subMenu,
        isActive: !subMenu.isActive
      };
    } else {
      if (subMenu.subMenu) {
        const nestedSubmenu = getActivations(menuItemId, subMenu);

        const temp = {
          ...subMenu,
          subMenu: nestedSubmenu,
          isActive: nestedSubmenu.some((item: SubMenuType) => item.isActive)
        };
        return temp;
      }
      return { ...subMenu, isActive: false };
    }
  });

  return preparedData;
};

const hideActivation = () => {
  menuItemData.value = menuItemData.value.map((item) => {
    if (item.subMenu) {
      const nestedSubmenu = item.subMenu.map((subMenu) => {
        return {
          ...subMenu,
          isActive: false
        };
      });
      return {
        ...item,
        isActive: false,
        subMenu: nestedSubmenu
      };
    }
    return { ...item, isActive: false };
  });
};

function handleDropdownMenu() {
  const dropdownToggleButtons = document
    .querySelector(".app-menu")
    ?.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-button");
  dropdownToggleButtons?.forEach((button) => {
    const content = button.nextElementSibling;
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (!content) {
        return;
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        // get the dropdown menu element
        var dropdownMenu = button;
        const subMenus: any = dropdownMenu.nextElementSibling
          ? dropdownMenu.nextElementSibling
          : dropdownMenu.parentElement?.nextElementSibling;
        if (subMenus) {
          const isLeftFull = subMenus.classList.contains(
            "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:ltr:md:left-full"
          );

          const isRightFull = subMenus.classList.contains(
            "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:rtl:md:right-full"
          );
          if (isLeftFull || isRightFull) {
            if (dropdownMenu && subMenus) {
              // get the position and dimensions of the dropdown menu
              var dropdownOffset = subMenus.getBoundingClientRect();
              var dropdownWidth = subMenus.offsetWidth;
              var dropdownHeight = subMenus.offsetHeight;

              // get the dimensions of the screen
              var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
              var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

              // calculate the maximum x and y coordinates of the dropdown menu
              var maxDropdownX = dropdownOffset.left + dropdownWidth;
              var maxDropdownY = dropdownOffset.top + dropdownHeight;

              // check if the dropdown menu goes outside the screen
              var isDropdownOffScreen =
                maxDropdownX > screenWidth || maxDropdownY > screenHeight;
              if (isDropdownOffScreen) {
                if (isLeftFull) {
                  subMenus.classList.remove(
                    "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:ltr:md:left-full"
                  );
                  subMenus.classList.add(
                    "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:ltr:md:right-full"
                  );
                }
              } else if (isRightFull) {
                subMenus.classList.add(
                  "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:rtl:md:left-full"
                );
                subMenus.classList.remove(
                  "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:rtl:md:right-full"
                );
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, 10);
    });
  });
}
</script>
<template>
  <div
    class="app-menu w-vertical-menu bg-vertical-menu ltr:border-r rtl:border-l border-vertical-menu-border fixed bottom-0 top-0 z-drawer md:z-[1003] transition-all duration-75 ease-linear group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:w-vertical-menu-md group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:w-vertical-menu-sm group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:pt-header group-data-[sidebar=dark]:bg-vertical-menu-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:border-vertical-menu-dark group-data-[sidebar=brand]:bg-vertical-menu-brand group-data-[sidebar=brand]:border-vertical-menu-brand group-data-[sidebar=modern]:bg-gradient-to-tr group-data-[sidebar=modern]:to-vertical-menu-to-modern group-data-[sidebar=modern]:from-vertical-menu-form-modern group-data-[layout=horizontal]:w-full group-data-[layout=horizontal]:bottom-auto group-data-[layout=horizontal]:top-header hidden md:block print:hidden group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:absolute group-data-[sidebar=modern]:border-vertical-menu-border-modern group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:bg-zink-700 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:border-t group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:border-zink-500 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:border-r-0 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:bg-zink-700 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:border-zink-600 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=scroll]:absolute group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=bordered]:top-[calc(theme('spacing.header')_+_theme('spacing.4'))] group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=bordered]:inset-x-4 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=hidden]:top-0 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=hidden]:h-16 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=bordered]:w-[calc(100%_-_2rem)] group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=bordered]:[&.sticky]:top-header group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=bordered]:rounded-b-md group-data-[layout=horizontal]:shadow-md group-data-[layout=horizontal]:shadow-slate-500/10 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:shadow-zink-500/10 [layout=horizontal]:ltr:pl-0 [layout=horizontal]:rtl:pr-0 md:group-data-[layout=horizontal]:z-10"
  >
    <div
      class="flex items-center justify-center px-5 text-center h-header group-data-[layout=horizontal]:hidden group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:fixed group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:top-0 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:bg-vertical-menu group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=dark]:bg-vertical-menu-dark group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=brand]:bg-vertical-menu-brand group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=modern]:bg-gradient-to-br group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=modern]:to-vertical-menu-to-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=modern]:from-vertical-menu-form-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=modern]:bg-vertical-menu-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:z-10 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:w-[calc(theme('spacing.vertical-menu-sm')_-_1px)] group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:bg-zink-700"
    >
      <div
        @click="onLogoClick"
        class="group-data-[sidebar=dark]:hidden group-data-[sidebar=brand]:hidden group-data-[sidebar=modern]:hidden cursor-pointer"
      >
        <span class="hidden group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:block">
          <img :src="logoSm" alt="" class="h-10 mx-auto" />
        </span>
        <span class="group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:hidden">
          <img :src="logoDark" alt="" class="h-14 mx-auto" />
        </span>
      </div>
      <div
        @click="onLogoClick"
        class="hidden group-data-[sidebar=dark]:block group-data-[sidebar=brand]:block group-data-[sidebar=modern]:block cursor-pointer"
      >
        <span class="hidden group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:block">
          <img :src="logoSm" alt="" class="h-6 mx-auto" />
        </span>
        <span class="group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:hidden">
          <img :src="logoLight" alt="" class="h-14 mx-auto" />
        </span>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="hidden p-0 float-end" id="vertical-hover">
        <i class="ri-record-circle-line"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <component
      :is="sideBarComponent"
      id="menu-scrollbar"
      class="group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:max-h-[calc(100vh_-_theme('spacing.header')_*_1.2)] group-data-[sidebar-size=lg]:max-h-[calc(100vh_-_theme('spacing.header')_*_1.2)] group-data-[layout=horizontal]:h-56 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:md:h-auto group-data-[layout=horizontal]:overflow-auto group-data-[layout=horizontal]:md:overflow-visible group-data-[layout=horizontal]:max-w-screen-2xl group-data-[layout=horizontal]:mx-auto"
    >
      <div>
        <ul
          class="group-data-[layout=horizontal]:flex group-data-[layout=horizontal]:flex-col group-data-[layout=horizontal]:md:flex-row"
          id="navbar-nav"
        >
          <template v-for="menuItem in menuItemData" :key="menuItem.title">
            <li
              v-if="menuItem.isHeader"
              class="px-4 py-1 text-vertical-menu-item group-data-[sidebar=dark]:text-vertical-menu-item-dark group-data-[sidebar=brand]:text-vertical-menu-item-brand group-data-[sidebar=modern]:text-vertical-menu-item-modern uppercase font-medium text-[11px] cursor-default tracking-wider group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:hidden group-data-[layout=horizontal]:hidden inline-block group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:block group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:underline group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:text-center group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:text-zink-200"
            >
              <span :data-key="`t-${menuItem.title}`">
                <!-- {!! $t(`t-${menuItem.title}`) !!} -->
                {{ menuItem.title }}
              </span>
            </li>
            <template v-else-if="menuItem.subMenu">
              <SubMenu
                :menuItem="menuItem"
                @toggleActivation="toggleActivation"
              />
            </template>
            <li
              v-else-if="!menuItem.subMenu && menuItem.path"
              class="relative group-data-[layout=horizontal]:shrink-0 group/sm"
            >
              <router-link
                class="relative flex items-center ltr:pl-3 rtl:pr-3 ltr:pr-5 rtl:pl-5 mx-3 my-1 group/menu-link text-vertical-menu-item-font-size font-normal transition-all duration-75 ease-linear rounded-md py-2.5 text-vertical-menu-item hover:text-vertical-menu-item-hover hover:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-hover [&.active]:text-vertical-menu-item-active [&.active]:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-active group-data-[sidebar=dark]:text-vertical-menu-item-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:hover:text-vertical-menu-item-hover-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:hover:text-custom-500 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:hover:text-custom-500 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:hover:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-hover-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:hover:bg-zink-600 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:[&.active]:text-vertical-menu-item-active-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:[&.active]:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-dark group-data-[sidebar=brand]:text-vertical-menu-item-brand group-data-[sidebar=brand]:hover:text-vertical-menu-item-hover-brand group-data-[sidebar=brand]:hover:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-hover-brand group-data-[sidebar=brand]:[&.active]:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-brand group-data-[sidebar=brand]:[&.active]:text-vertical-menu-item-active-brand group-data-[sidebar=modern]:text-vertical-menu-item-modern group-data-[sidebar=modern]:hover:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-hover-modern group-data-[sidebar=modern]:hover:text-vertical-menu-item-hover-modern group-data-[sidebar=modern]:[&.active]:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-modern group-data-[sidebar=modern]:[&.active]:text-vertical-menu-item-active-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:block group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:text-center group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-hover/sm:w-[calc(theme('spacing.vertical-menu-sm')_*_3.63)] group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-hover/sm:bg-vertical-menu group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=dark]:group-hover/sm:bg-vertical-menu-dark group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=modern]:group-hover/sm:bg-vertical-menu-border-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=brand]:group-hover/sm:bg-vertical-menu-brand group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:my-0 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:m-0 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:ltr:pr-8 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:rtl:pl-8 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:hover:bg-transparent group-data-[layout=horizontal]:[&.active]:bg-transparent [&.dropdown-button]:before:absolute [&.dropdown-button]:[&.show]:before:content-['\ea4e'] [&.dropdown-button]:before:content-['\ea6e'] [&.dropdown-button]:before:font-remix ltr:[&.dropdown-button]:before:right-2 rtl:[&.dropdown-button]:before:left-2 [&.dropdown-button]:before:text-16 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:[&.dropdown-button]:before:hidden group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:[&.dropdown-button]:before:hidden group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:text-zink-200 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:text-zink-200 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:[&.active]:dark:bg-zink-600 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:[&.active]:text-custom-500 rtl:[&.dropdown-button]:before:rotate-180 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:[&.dropdown-button]:before:rotate-90 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:[&.dropdown-button]:[&.show]:before:rotate-0 rtl:[&.dropdown-button]:[&.show]:before:rotate-0"
                :class="{
                  active: path === menuItem.path
                }"
                :to="menuItem.path"
                @click="toggleActivation"
              >
                <span
                  class="min-w-[1.75rem] group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:h-[1.75rem] inline-block text-start text-[16px] group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:block"
                >
                  <component
                    :is="menuItem.icon"
                    class="h-4 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:h-5 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:w-5 transition group-hover/menu-link:animate-icons fill-slate-100 group-hover/menu-link:fill-blue-200 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:fill-zink-600 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:fill-zink-600 group-data-[sidebar=brand]:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-brand group-data-[sidebar=modern]:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-modern group-data-[sidebar=dark]:group-hover/menu-link:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:group-hover/menu-link:dark:fill-custom-500/20 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:group-hover/menu-link:fill-custom-500/20 group-data-[sidebar=brand]:group-hover/menu-link:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-brand group-data-[sidebar=modern]:group-hover/menu-link:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:block group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:mx-auto group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:mb-2"
                  />
                </span>
                <span
                  class="group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:ltr:pl-10 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:rtl:pr-10 align-middle group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-hover/sm:block group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:hidden"
                  :data-key="`t-${menuItem.title}`"
                >
                  <!--{{ $t(`t-${menuItem.title}`) }}-->
                  {{ menuItem.title }}
                </span>
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </component>
  </div>
</template>


This code calls the function getMenuItems which is another file and looks like this:
import {
  MonitorDot,
  BuildingIcon,
  TableIcon,
  Users2,
  UserIcon,
  CalendarIcon,
  CreditCardIcon,
  LogOutIcon,
  SettingsIcon,
  UserCogIcon
} from "lucide-vue-next";
import { MenuItemType } from "@/app/layout/types";

export function getMenuItems(t): MenuItemType[] {
  return [
    { isHeader: true, title: "Menu" },
    {
      icon: MonitorDot,
      title: t.value?.general?.home,
      path: "/"
    },
    {
      icon: BuildingIcon,
      title: t.value?.general?.organisations,
      path: "/organisations"
    },
    {
      icon: BuildingIcon,
      title: t.value?.general?.buildings,
      path: "/buildings"
    },
    {
      icon: TableIcon,
      title: t.value?.general?.classrooms,
      path: "/classrooms"
    },
    {
      icon: Users2,
      title: t.value?.general?.classes,
      path: "/classes"
    },
    {
      icon: UserIcon,
      title: t.value?.general?.teachers,
      path: "/teachers"
    },
    {
      icon: Users2,
      title: t.value?.general?.students,
      path: "/students"
    },
    {
      icon: Users2,
      title: "Administration",
      path: "/administration"
    },
    {
      icon: UserIcon,
      title: t.value?.general?.subjects,
      path: "/subjects"
    },
    {
      icon: CalendarIcon,
      title: t.value?.general?.calendars,
      path: "/calendar"
    },
    {
      icon: CreditCardIcon,
      title: "Payments",
      path: "/payments"
    },
    { isHeader: true, title: "settings" },
    {
      icon: UserCogIcon,
      title: t.value?.general?.profile,
      path: "/profile"
    },
    {
      icon: Users2,
      title: t.value?.general?.teams,
      path: "/teams"
    },
    {
      icon: Users2,
      title: t.value?.general?.users,
      path: "/users"
    },
    {
      icon: SettingsIcon,
      title: "Settings",
      path: "/settings"
    },
    {
      icon: LogOutIcon,
      title: t.value?.general?.logout,
      path: "/logout"
    },
  ];
}


I have an issue where my translations are not reactive.
Even when I put watch on t variable the elements on the screen are not changed but I can see that t changes in console.log every time without any issues.
Can somebody help?
I have tried using watch property from vue like this but that didn't help:
watch(t, (newValue) => {
  menuItems.value = getMenuItems(newValue);

  console.log(menuItems.value);
});

If I console.log t variable, I get that is changed but menuItems.value get some undefined values, but I have the translations inside (they are stored in localStorage).
You can also check my store for language:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import { updateTranslations } from '@/assets/lang';

export interface Translation {
  [key: string]: string;
}

interface AppState {
  locale: string;
  translations: Translation;
}

export const useAppStore = defineStore("app", {
  state: (): AppState => ({
    locale: 'en', // Default locale
    translations: {}, // Translations object
  }),
  actions: {
    async changeLanguage(locale: string) {
        try {
          const translations = await updateTranslations(locale);
          if (translations === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Translations not found');
          }
          this.locale = locale;
          this.translations = translations;

        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error changing language:', error);
        }
    },
    async initializeApp() {
      try {
        // Check if locale is stored in local storage, if not, fallback to default locale
        const storedLocale = localStorage.getItem('locale');
        const defaultLocale = storedLocale || import.meta.env.VITE_APP_DEFAULT_LOCALE;
        
        const translations = await updateTranslations(defaultLocale);
        if (translations === undefined) {
          throw new Error('Translations not found');
        }

        this.translations = translations;
        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error initializing app:', error);
        // Handle error gracefully, e.g., show a message to the user
      }
    },
    async updateTranslations(locale: string): Promise<Translation> {
        try {
          const translations = await updateTranslations(locale);
          if (translations === undefined) {
            throw new Error('Translations not found');
          }
          return translations;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error updating translations:', error);
          // Handle error gracefully
          throw error;
        }
      }  
  },
});

export default createPinia();

And my code for the changing the languge (vue component):
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { usFlag } from "@/assets/images/flags/utils";
import { languagesData } from "@/app/layout/navbar/utils";
import NavBtn from "@/app/layout/navbar/Button.vue";
import { onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import { useAppStore } from '@/store/index';

defineProps({
  showName: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

const LanguageStore = useAppStore();

const langTitle = ref("English");
const langFlagSrc = ref(usFlag); 

const setLanguage = async (entry: { [key: string]: string }) => {
  const { src, lang, title } = entry;
  const element = document.getElementById('header-lang-img');
  
  if (element) {
    element.setAttribute('src', src);
  }

  // Call changeLanguage function from Pinia store
  await LanguageStore.changeLanguage(lang);
  // Update langTitle with the selected language
  langTitle.value = title;
  langFlagSrc.value = src;

  // Store the selected language in local storage
  localStorage.setItem('selectedLanguage', lang);

  // Reload the page after changing the language
  window.location.reload();
};

// Set the selected language from local storage on component mount
onMounted(() => {
  const selectedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage');
  if (selectedLanguage) {
    LanguageStore.changeLanguage(selectedLanguage);
    // Optionally, update langTitle and langFlagSrc with the selected language
    const languageEntry = languagesData.find(entry => entry.lang === selectedLanguage);
    if (languageEntry) {
      langTitle.value = languageEntry.title;
      langFlagSrc.value = languageEntry.src;
    }
  }
});
</script>


<template>
  <TList :items="languagesData" placement="bottom-start">
    <template #title>
      <button
        v-if="showName"
        type="button"
        class="inline-flex items-center gap-3 transition-all duration-200 ease-linear dropdown-toggle btn border-slate-200 dark:border-zink-400/60 group/items focus:border-custom-500 dark:focus:border-custom-500"
      >
        <img
          :src="langFlagSrc"
          alt="language-flag"
          id="header-lang-img"
          class="object-cover h-5 rounded-full"
        />
        <h6
          class="text-base font-medium transition-all duration-200 ease-linear text-slate-600 group-hover/items:text-custom-500 dark:text-zink-200 dark:group-hover/items:text-custom-500"
        >
          {{ langTitle }}
        </h6>
      </button>
      <NavBtn class="dropdown" v-else>
        <img
          :src="langFlagSrc"
          alt="language-flag"
          id="header-lang-img"
          class="h-5 rounded-sm"
        />
      </NavBtn>
    </template>
    <template #default="{ data }">
      <div
        class="flex items-center gap-3 group/items language"
        :data-lang="data.lang"
        :title="data.title"
        @click.prevent="setLanguage(data)"
      >
        <img :src="data.src" alt="" class="object-cover h-4 rounded-full" />
        <h6
          class="transition-all duration-200 ease-linear font-15medium text- text-slate-600 dark:text-zink-200 group-hover/items:text-custom-500"
        >
          {{ data.title }}
        </h6>
      </div>
    </template>
  </TList>
</template>



getMenuItems was hardcoded to accept a ref, and newValue is not a ref. Also, you could use a computed instead.

Thanks, do you have a solution, how to do that?

I have tried this, but it didn't help (elements on the screen are still not changing):
const menuItems = ref<MenuItemType[]>([]);
menuItems.value = getMenuItems(t);
// Define a ref for newValue
const newValueRef = ref(null);
watch(t, (newValue) => {
// Assign the value to newValueRef
newValueRef.value = newValue;
// Now newValueRef behaves like a ref
console.log(isRef(newValueRef)); // This will print true
menuItems.value = getMenuItems(newValue);
});

watch(t, () => { menuItems.value = getMenuItems(t) }). Or better const menuItems = computed(() => getMenuItems(t)) because this is the case for a computed

Tried both ways, no errors, but still, elements are not reactive.

Where exactly? For instance, mappedData is not reactive, anything that depends on reactive data should be within watch() or computed. if it's where you observe the problem then that's it. The example is bulky, you need https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can be reproduced if you want the problem to be solved for sure

That was my question exactly. What else should I put in watch or have computed in here. mappedData is used to show all the elements on the page as you can see in the code.  How to do that?

Your code is too big for regular SO question, see what https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is about. Other users have to review it including irrelevant parts without seeing how it really works, this is the reason SO has this rule. Anything that is computed from another reactive value, needs to be computed(), that's the purpose of it. In your case it needs to be const mappedData = computed(() => ...). I can't say without thorough checking how this will affect the way you update, e.g. here updatedMenuItems: any = [...visibleItems]

I understand, thank you for your help.
Like I said, I am working with code which is template and it is not mine, so I also have a hard time navigating stuff (no code docs). This is why it would take me a lot of time to create MCVE and why it is easier for me try to get solution like this.
Anyway, thank you!

UPDATE, this is the answer to my problem:


<script lang="ts" setup>
import { computed, ref, onMounted, watch, onBeforeUnmount } from "vue";
import { useRoute, useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { logoDark, logoLight, logoSm } from "@/assets/images/utils";
import { getMenuItems } from "@/app/layout/utils";
import SubMenu from "@/app/layout/menu/SubMenu.vue";
import { useLayoutStore } from "@/store/layout";
import { LucideNetwork } from "lucide-vue-next";
import { LAYOUTS, SIDEBAR_SIZE } from "@/app/const";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { MenuItemType, SubMenuType } from "@/app/layout/types";
import { useAppStore } from '@/store/index';

const layoutStore = computed(() => useLayoutStore());
const layoutType = computed(() => layoutStore.value.layoutType);
const isHorizontal = computed(() => layoutType.value === LAYOUTS.HORIZONTAL);

const route = useRoute();
const router = useRouter();
const path = computed(() => route.path);

const LanguageStore = useAppStore();
const t = computed(() => LanguageStore.translations);

let menuItems = computed(() => getMenuItems(t));

watch(t, () => { updateMenuData(); })

const sideBarComponent = computed(() => {
  const sideBarSize = layoutStore.value.sideBarSize;

  if (sideBarSize === SIDEBAR_SIZE.SMALL) {
    return "div";
  } else {
    return "simplebar";
  }
});
const onLogoClick = () => {
  router.push("/");
};

const clientWidth = ref(document.documentElement.clientWidth);

const menuItemData = ref<MenuItemType[]>([]);
const mappedData = ref<MenuItemType[]>([]);

const onWindowResize = () => {
  clientWidth.value = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  if (isHorizontal.value) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setupHorizontalMenu();
    }, 300);
  } else {
    menuItemData.value = mappedData.value;
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);

  if (isHorizontal.value) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setupHorizontalMenu();
    }, 300);
  }
  document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", (event: any) => {
    isSubMenu(event.target);
  });
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  document.documentElement.removeEventListener("click", (event: any) => {
    isSubMenu(event.target);
  });
  window.removeEventListener("resize", setupHorizontalMenu);
  window.removeEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
});

const isSubMenu = (element: HTMLElement | null): boolean => {
  if (!element) {
    hideActivation();
    return false;
  }
  return (
    element.classList.contains("submenu-dropdown") ||
    element.classList.contains("app-menu") ||
    isSubMenu(element.parentElement)
  );
};

watch(layoutType, (newVal: string) => {
  if (newVal === LAYOUTS.HORIZONTAL) {
    setupHorizontalMenu();
  } else {
    menuItemData.value = mappedData.value;
  }
});

const setupHorizontalMenu = () => {
  if (clientWidth.value >= 768) {
    window.addEventListener("resize", setupHorizontalMenu);

    let isMoreMenu = false;
    const navData = mappedData.value.filter(
      (menuItem: MenuItemType) => !menuItem.isHeader
    );
    const horizontalMenuEle = document.querySelector(".app-menu");
    const navbarNav = document.querySelector(".navbar-header");
    if (navbarNav) {
      const fullMenuWidth = navbarNav.clientWidth - 100 || 0;

      let totalItemsWidth = 0;
      let visibleItems: MenuItemType[] = [];
      let hiddenItems: MenuItemType[] = []; // Add type annotation here

      for (let i = 0; i < navData.length; i++) {
        const element: HTMLElement = horizontalMenuEle?.querySelector(
          "#navbar-nav"
        )?.children[i] as HTMLElement;
        const itemWidth = element?.offsetWidth || 0;
        totalItemsWidth += itemWidth;

        if (totalItemsWidth + 250 <= fullMenuWidth) {
          visibleItems.push(navData[i]);
        } else {
          hiddenItems.push(navData[i]);
        }
      }

      const moreMenuItem = {
        title: "more",
        icon: LucideNetwork,
        isActive: false,
        subMenu: hiddenItems,
        id: uuidv4(),
        stateVariables: isMoreMenu,
        click: (e: any) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          isMoreMenu = !isMoreMenu;
        }
      };

      let updatedMenuItems: any = [...visibleItems];
      if (hiddenItems.length) {
        updatedMenuItems.push(moreMenuItem);
      }

      menuItemData.value = updatedMenuItems;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      handleDropdownMenu();
    }, 500);
  } else {
    menuItemData.value = mappedData.value;
  }
};

const toggleActivation = (menuItemId: string) => {
  let hasSubMenu = false; // Flag to track if the element has submenu items

  menuItemData.value = menuItemData.value.map((item: MenuItemType) => {
    if (item.id === menuItemId) {
      return {
        ...item,
        isActive: !item.isActive
      };
    } else if (item.subMenu) {
      const nestedSubmenu = getActivations(menuItemId, item);
      const firstLevelMenu = {
        ...item,
        isActive: nestedSubmenu.some(
          (subMenu: SubMenuType) => subMenu.isActive
        ),
        subMenu: nestedSubmenu
      };

      // Update flag if submenu exists
      if (!hasSubMenu && nestedSubmenu.length > 0) {
        hasSubMenu = true;
      }

      return firstLevelMenu;
    }
    return { ...item, isActive: false };
  });

  // Call closeSidebar() only if the element doesn't have submenu items
  if (!hasSubMenu) {
    closeSidebar();
  }
};

const closeSidebar = () => {
  const backdropOverlay = document.querySelector(".backdrop-overlay");
  if (backdropOverlay instanceof HTMLElement) {
    backdropOverlay.click();
  }
};

const getActivations: any = (menuItemId: string, menuItem: MenuItemType) => {
  const preparedData = menuItem.subMenu?.map((subMenu: SubMenuType) => {
    if (menuItemId && subMenu.id === menuItemId) {
      return {
        ...subMenu,
        isActive: !subMenu.isActive
      };
    } else {
      if (subMenu.subMenu) {
        const nestedSubmenu = getActivations(menuItemId, subMenu);

        const temp = {
          ...subMenu,
          subMenu: nestedSubmenu,
          isActive: nestedSubmenu.some((item: SubMenuType) => item.isActive)
        };
        return temp;
      }
      return { ...subMenu, isActive: false };
    }
  });

  return preparedData;
};

const hideActivation = () => {
  menuItemData.value = menuItemData.value.map((item) => {
    if (item.subMenu) {
      const nestedSubmenu = item.subMenu.map((subMenu) => {
        return {
          ...subMenu,
          isActive: false
        };
      });
      return {
        ...item,
        isActive: false,
        subMenu: nestedSubmenu
      };
    }
    return { ...item, isActive: false };
  });
};

function handleDropdownMenu() {
  const dropdownToggleButtons = document
    .querySelector(".app-menu")
    ?.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-button");
  dropdownToggleButtons?.forEach((button) => {
    const content = button.nextElementSibling;
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (!content) {
        return;
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        // get the dropdown menu element
        var dropdownMenu = button;
        const subMenus: any = dropdownMenu.nextElementSibling
          ? dropdownMenu.nextElementSibling
          : dropdownMenu.parentElement?.nextElementSibling;
        if (subMenus) {
          const isLeftFull = subMenus.classList.contains(
            "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:ltr:md:left-full"
          );

          const isRightFull = subMenus.classList.contains(
            "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:rtl:md:right-full"
          );
          if (isLeftFull || isRightFull) {
            if (dropdownMenu && subMenus) {
              // get the position and dimensions of the dropdown menu
              var dropdownOffset = subMenus.getBoundingClientRect();
              var dropdownWidth = subMenus.offsetWidth;
              var dropdownHeight = subMenus.offsetHeight;

              // get the dimensions of the screen
              var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
              var screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

              // calculate the maximum x and y coordinates of the dropdown menu
              var maxDropdownX = dropdownOffset.left + dropdownWidth;
              var maxDropdownY = dropdownOffset.top + dropdownHeight;

              // check if the dropdown menu goes outside the screen
              var isDropdownOffScreen =
                maxDropdownX > screenWidth || maxDropdownY > screenHeight;
              if (isDropdownOffScreen) {
                if (isLeftFull) {
                  subMenus.classList.remove(
                    "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:ltr:md:left-full"
                  );
                  subMenus.classList.add(
                    "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:ltr:md:right-full"
                  );
                }
              } else if (isRightFull) {
                subMenus.classList.add(
                  "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:rtl:md:left-full"
                );
                subMenus.classList.remove(
                  "group-data-[layout=horizontal]:rtl:md:right-full"
                );
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, 10);
    });
  });
}

function updateMenuData() {
  // Update menuItems
  menuItems = computed(() => getMenuItems(t));

  // Update mappedData
  updateMappedData();

  // Update menuItemData
  menuItemData.value = mappedData.value;

  // Call setupHorizontalMenu if layout is horizontal
  if (isHorizontal.value) {
    setupHorizontalMenu();
  }
}

function updateMappedData() {
  mappedData.value = menuItems.value.map((item) => {
    if (item.subMenu) {
      const nestedSubMenu = item.subMenu.map((subMenu: SubMenuType) => {
        if (subMenu.subMenu) {
          return {
            ...subMenu,
            isActive: false,
            id: uuidv4()
          };
        }
        return {
          ...subMenu
        };
      });

      return {
        ...item,
        subMenu: nestedSubMenu,
        isActive: false,
        id: uuidv4()
      };
    }
    return {
      ...item,
      id: uuidv4()
    };
  });
}
</script>
<template>
  <div
    class="app-menu w-vertical-menu bg-vertical-menu ltr:border-r rtl:border-l border-vertical-menu-border fixed bottom-0 top-0 z-drawer md:z-[1003] transition-all duration-75 ease-linear group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:w-vertical-menu-md group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:w-vertical-menu-sm group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:pt-header group-data-[sidebar=dark]:bg-vertical-menu-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:border-vertical-menu-dark group-data-[sidebar=brand]:bg-vertical-menu-brand group-data-[sidebar=brand]:border-vertical-menu-brand group-data-[sidebar=modern]:bg-gradient-to-tr group-data-[sidebar=modern]:to-vertical-menu-to-modern group-data-[sidebar=modern]:from-vertical-menu-form-modern group-data-[layout=horizontal]:w-full group-data-[layout=horizontal]:bottom-auto group-data-[layout=horizontal]:top-header hidden md:block print:hidden group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:absolute group-data-[sidebar=modern]:border-vertical-menu-border-modern group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:bg-zink-700 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:border-t group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:border-zink-500 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:border-r-0 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:bg-zink-700 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:border-zink-600 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=scroll]:absolute group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=bordered]:top-[calc(theme('spacing.header')_+_theme('spacing.4'))] group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=bordered]:inset-x-4 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=hidden]:top-0 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=hidden]:h-16 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=bordered]:w-[calc(100%_-_2rem)] group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=bordered]:[&.sticky]:top-header group-data-[layout=horizontal]:group-data-[navbar=bordered]:rounded-b-md group-data-[layout=horizontal]:shadow-md group-data-[layout=horizontal]:shadow-slate-500/10 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:shadow-zink-500/10 [layout=horizontal]:ltr:pl-0 [layout=horizontal]:rtl:pr-0 md:group-data-[layout=horizontal]:z-10"
  >
    <div
      class="flex items-center justify-center px-5 text-center h-header group-data-[layout=horizontal]:hidden group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:fixed group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:top-0 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:bg-vertical-menu group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=dark]:bg-vertical-menu-dark group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=brand]:bg-vertical-menu-brand group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=modern]:bg-gradient-to-br group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=modern]:to-vertical-menu-to-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=modern]:from-vertical-menu-form-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=modern]:bg-vertical-menu-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:z-10 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:w-[calc(theme('spacing.vertical-menu-sm')_-_1px)] group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:bg-zink-700"
    >
      <div
        @click="onLogoClick"
        class="group-data-[sidebar=dark]:hidden group-data-[sidebar=brand]:hidden group-data-[sidebar=modern]:hidden cursor-pointer"
      >
        <span class="hidden group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:block">
          <img :src="logoSm" alt="" class="h-10 mx-auto" />
        </span>
        <span class="group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:hidden">
          <img :src="logoDark" alt="" class="h-14 mx-auto" />
        </span>
      </div>
      <div
        @click="onLogoClick"
        class="hidden group-data-[sidebar=dark]:block group-data-[sidebar=brand]:block group-data-[sidebar=modern]:block cursor-pointer"
      >
        <span class="hidden group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:block">
          <img :src="logoSm" alt="" class="h-6 mx-auto" />
        </span>
        <span class="group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:hidden">
          <img :src="logoLight" alt="" class="h-14 mx-auto" />
        </span>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="hidden p-0 float-end" id="vertical-hover">
        <i class="ri-record-circle-line"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
    <component
      :is="sideBarComponent"
      id="menu-scrollbar"
      class="group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:max-h-[calc(100vh_-_theme('spacing.header')_*_1.2)] group-data-[sidebar-size=lg]:max-h-[calc(100vh_-_theme('spacing.header')_*_1.2)] group-data-[layout=horizontal]:h-56 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:md:h-auto group-data-[layout=horizontal]:overflow-auto group-data-[layout=horizontal]:md:overflow-visible group-data-[layout=horizontal]:max-w-screen-2xl group-data-[layout=horizontal]:mx-auto"
    >
      <div>
        <ul
          class="group-data-[layout=horizontal]:flex group-data-[layout=horizontal]:flex-col group-data-[layout=horizontal]:md:flex-row"
          id="navbar-nav"
        >
          <template v-for="menuItem in menuItemData" :key="menuItem.title">
            <li
              v-if="menuItem.isHeader"
              class="px-4 py-1 text-vertical-menu-item group-data-[sidebar=dark]:text-vertical-menu-item-dark group-data-[sidebar=brand]:text-vertical-menu-item-brand group-data-[sidebar=modern]:text-vertical-menu-item-modern uppercase font-medium text-[11px] cursor-default tracking-wider group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:hidden group-data-[layout=horizontal]:hidden inline-block group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:block group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:underline group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:text-center group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:text-zink-200"
            >
              <span :data-key="`t-${menuItem.title}`">
                <!-- {!! $t(`t-${menuItem.title}`) !!} -->
                {{ menuItem.title }}
              </span>
            </li>
            <template v-else-if="menuItem.subMenu">
              <SubMenu
                :menuItem="menuItem"
                @toggleActivation="toggleActivation"
              />
            </template>
            <li
              v-else-if="!menuItem.subMenu && menuItem.path"
              class="relative group-data-[layout=horizontal]:shrink-0 group/sm"
            >
              <router-link
                class="relative flex items-center ltr:pl-3 rtl:pr-3 ltr:pr-5 rtl:pl-5 mx-3 my-1 group/menu-link text-vertical-menu-item-font-size font-normal transition-all duration-75 ease-linear rounded-md py-2.5 text-vertical-menu-item hover:text-vertical-menu-item-hover hover:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-hover [&.active]:text-vertical-menu-item-active [&.active]:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-active group-data-[sidebar=dark]:text-vertical-menu-item-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:hover:text-vertical-menu-item-hover-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:hover:text-custom-500 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:hover:text-custom-500 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:hover:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-hover-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:hover:bg-zink-600 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:[&.active]:text-vertical-menu-item-active-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:[&.active]:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-dark group-data-[sidebar=brand]:text-vertical-menu-item-brand group-data-[sidebar=brand]:hover:text-vertical-menu-item-hover-brand group-data-[sidebar=brand]:hover:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-hover-brand group-data-[sidebar=brand]:[&.active]:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-brand group-data-[sidebar=brand]:[&.active]:text-vertical-menu-item-active-brand group-data-[sidebar=modern]:text-vertical-menu-item-modern group-data-[sidebar=modern]:hover:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-hover-modern group-data-[sidebar=modern]:hover:text-vertical-menu-item-hover-modern group-data-[sidebar=modern]:[&.active]:bg-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-modern group-data-[sidebar=modern]:[&.active]:text-vertical-menu-item-active-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:block group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:text-center group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-hover/sm:w-[calc(theme('spacing.vertical-menu-sm')_*_3.63)] group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-hover/sm:bg-vertical-menu group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=dark]:group-hover/sm:bg-vertical-menu-dark group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=modern]:group-hover/sm:bg-vertical-menu-border-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-data-[sidebar=brand]:group-hover/sm:bg-vertical-menu-brand group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:my-0 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:m-0 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:ltr:pr-8 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:rtl:pl-8 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:hover:bg-transparent group-data-[layout=horizontal]:[&.active]:bg-transparent [&.dropdown-button]:before:absolute [&.dropdown-button]:[&.show]:before:content-['\ea4e'] [&.dropdown-button]:before:content-['\ea6e'] [&.dropdown-button]:before:font-remix ltr:[&.dropdown-button]:before:right-2 rtl:[&.dropdown-button]:before:left-2 [&.dropdown-button]:before:text-16 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:[&.dropdown-button]:before:hidden group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:[&.dropdown-button]:before:hidden group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:text-zink-200 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:text-zink-200 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:[&.active]:dark:bg-zink-600 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:[&.active]:text-custom-500 rtl:[&.dropdown-button]:before:rotate-180 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:[&.dropdown-button]:before:rotate-90 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:[&.dropdown-button]:[&.show]:before:rotate-0 rtl:[&.dropdown-button]:[&.show]:before:rotate-0"
                :class="{
                  active: path === menuItem.path
                }"
                :to="menuItem.path"
                @click="toggleActivation"
              >
                <span
                  class="min-w-[1.75rem] group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:h-[1.75rem] inline-block text-start text-[16px] group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:block"
                >
                  <component
                    :is="menuItem.icon"
                    class="h-4 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:h-5 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:w-5 transition group-hover/menu-link:animate-icons fill-slate-100 group-hover/menu-link:fill-blue-200 group-data-[sidebar=dark]:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:dark:fill-zink-600 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:fill-zink-600 group-data-[sidebar=brand]:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-brand group-data-[sidebar=modern]:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-modern group-data-[sidebar=dark]:group-hover/menu-link:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-dark group-data-[sidebar=dark]:group-hover/menu-link:dark:fill-custom-500/20 group-data-[layout=horizontal]:dark:group-hover/menu-link:fill-custom-500/20 group-data-[sidebar=brand]:group-hover/menu-link:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-brand group-data-[sidebar=modern]:group-hover/menu-link:fill-vertical-menu-item-bg-active-modern group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:block group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:mx-auto group-data-[sidebar-size=md]:mb-2"
                  />
                </span>
                <span
                  class="group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:ltr:pl-10 group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:rtl:pr-10 align-middle group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:group-hover/sm:block group-data-[sidebar-size=sm]:hidden"
                  :data-key="`t-${menuItem.title}`"
                >
                  <!--{{ $t(`t-${menuItem.title}`) }}-->
                  {{ menuItem.title }}
                </span>
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </template>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </component>
  </div>
</template>



I had to put the whole mapping part inside the function and call that function every time t changes (updateMenuData()). Now, reactivity works. Thanks everyone for the help!

It's a mistake to put computed inside watch, this is what happens when you call updateMenuData

Well, it works, there are no errors, so it is good enough for me for now.
I am working with the template from others so that's why this is really complex, 60% of code is not mine and it is hard to navigate through it.

I see. You need to be prepared that it will behave unpredictably because this is not documented usage, a computed never was intended to be used like that.

Ok, I will watch for that. Thank you
